# RouterOutlet Angular 15

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an error with running the angular project

> X [ERROR] NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:
> If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]

here is app.component.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

here is app.component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, RouterOutlet} from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'Docs';

  constructor(private _router: Router) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this._router.navigate(['upload-pdf']).then(r=>console.log(r))
  }
}
```

here is app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, RouterOutlet, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {PdfComponent} from "../pdf/pdf.component";
import {UploadPdfComponent} from "../upload-pdf/upload-pdf.component";

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AppComponent },
  { path: 'pdf', component: PdfComponent},
  { path: 'upload-pdf', component: UploadPdfComponent},
  { path: '**', component: AppComponent },
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes), RouterOutlet],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

here is app.module.ts

```
import {CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import {PdfComponent} from "../pdf/pdf.component";
import {UploadPdfComponent} from "../upload-pdf/upload-pdf.component";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {MatFileUploadComponent, MatFileUploadModule, MatFileUploadQueueComponent} from "angular-material-fileupload";
import {RouterOutlet} from "@angular/router";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PdfComponent,
    UploadPdfComponent,
    MatFileUploadComponent,
    MatFileUploadQueueComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatFileUploadModule,
    RouterOutlet
  ],
  exports:[
    AppComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

here is app.config.ts

```
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app-routing.module';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes)]
};
```

this error disappeared when turn the component to standalone, is this error can solved by another solution?

Comment: You should add the `RouterModule` into the `imports` array of the `AppComponent`.Besides, I don't see any reason that you should import `RouterOutlet` in the `AppRoutingModule` and `AppModule`..

Answer (score 1):

The error mentioned informs that you need to import the `RouterModule` in the `AppComponent`.

```
import {Router, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css',
  imports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

And remove the imports of `RouterOutlet` in the `AppRoutingModule` and `AppModule` as it is unneeded.

For [stand-alone components](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components), you are allowed to import the `RouterOutlet` in the `imports` array.

```
import {Router, RouterOutlet} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css',
  imports: [RouterOutlet]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```